# Sentry crash reports with react native ignite app

Tags: react-native, sentry

I have setup react native ignite app with `sentry`

```
import App from "./app/app"
import React from "react"
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen"
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react-native';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://mydsn',
  debug: true, // If `true`,});
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

function IgniteApp() {
  return <App hideSplashScreen={SplashScreen.hideAsync} />
}

export default Sentry.wrap(IgniteApp);
```

If I manually trigger an error like the following code

```
<Button onPress={() => { throw new Error('New Error huray3!'); }}>Sentry</Button>
```

It works fine, but when I use the app and the app crashes I don't get any report for the crashed session.

I am running the app with expo go app on android.